# When will we have elections?

Tags: support, election

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [2012 Community Moderator Election](https://webmasters.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/810/2012-community-moderator-election)

I just looked at https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/election, and it looks like the last time that we had elections was over a year ago. I'm just wondering if there is some sort of schedule for elections, and if there is, if we're overdue for one.

Comment: +1 We're presently short one regular moderator, couldn't hurt to have another round of elections.

Comment: @danlefree I noticed that too, but from what I see, you and john are doing a good job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We will start a new election for you in a few weeks. Keep an eye out for it in July. :)

Answer (score 2):

Ben has already said he can't moderate anymore and, although two mods can handle this site fairly well, I would like to see another moderator take his place to add a fresh perspective to the issues that aren't quite so "black and white". And if one of us goes away for a week or so it leaves one mod with a lot of work. Maybe we can see if it is possible to have an election to add another mod to this site?

Comment: Sounds like a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

I looked into this a few months ago. Elections are not automatic every year. If the moderators are active, and haven't said they want to give up then elections don't need to be held. If the volume of questions was such that the existing moderators were struggling then there could be elections for a fourth moderator, but I don't think that's the case with this site.

[When do moderator elections take place?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99512/when-are-the-elections)

Comment: Doesn't sound democratic, does it? I suggest to either have a fixed annual or bi-annual election, whereas current and past moderators can be re-elected as many times they want ...